# Read sms when arrive on sdk 16+

Tags: android

I did set up a test app to read an incoming message on android 16 and above versions.

The Jelly bean powered device works beautifully, except the 16+ versions doesn't work as i expected. So the reason behind the problem is on 4.4 and above you can set up an app that can receive the sms as default by you.

In my test condition i have custom app by the sim provider(LTE). The custom app only can receive the incoming message. So i can't intercept the receiver.

I know the custom app has the highest priority can lead to abort the broadcast receiver that i implemented in my app.

All i need is to read those incoming message(a specific message for a purpose).

Please suggest any workaround.

Comment: "The custom app only can receive the incoming message.", "I know the custom app has the highest priority can lead to abort..." -- Neither of those things is generally true, barring any shenanigans by your OEM/carrier. If your app is successfully getting the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast on earlier versions, then my first thought would be that the newer device you're testing on has some sort of additional settings/permissions that disallow third-party apps from receiving SMS by default. Have a look through the device Settings, or in any security-related, or similar, app that might be present.

Comment: Thanks Mike...i know you have contributed very well in previous posts about SMS. Is there any workaround ?

Comment: I neglected to ask: which Android version are you testing on now, and what's your `targetSdkVersion`? If it's Marshmallow or above, with a `targetSdkVersion` >= 23, you might be running into the runtime permission problem, as SMS permissions are dangerous permissions.

Comment: I did test on 5.1 not on 6.0

Comment: OK, then if it is indeed a device setting/permission that's the cause, then the only direct way to remedy that would be for the user to disable that block, however that might be accomplished on their particular device. Apart from that, you could set a `ContentObserver` for the `content://sms` URI, and listen for changes to the Provider. However, you can't register a `ContentObserver` in the manifest, like you might a `BroadcastReceiver`. You'd have to have a running `Activity` or `Service` for that.

Comment: Also, if timeliness isn't a concern, you could just query the SMS Provider whenever your app runs, and check for the message you're looking for then.

Comment: good catch! let see what i can do with that.

Comment: I think i have sorted it out. Using NotificationListner i can intercept the specific message on 4.3.x + devices. Thanks! i'll post the answer soon.